# Do I have to wrap the wire around the outlet screw?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Trying to install this wall receptacle and can't tell by instructions if I have to wrap wire around the screw or can I just use the holes?[image]

Comment: That is a screw-and-clamp type receptacle.  You place the wire in the hole then tighten the screw.  It does not grab the wire like a backstab;  you must loosen the screw before insertion and tighten the screw after. It typically works with solid, stranded, 12 or 14 AWG wire.   You can also hook it like the ground wire; hooking it is the most secure connection, which is why it's required for ground.

Comment: The routing of that bare copper safety ground wire is positioned in a way that makes it likely that it will bend and touch the neutral breakaway tab when the receptacle is pushed into the electrical box. This would not be a desirable thing to have happen.

Comment: @Michael is right.  +1  At the very least it should be on the other side of the white wire.  Whenever you actually install an outlet things tend to get pushed together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this picture looks is perfect.

The ground screw is all out there naked so a straight wire would slip out.

The electrical contacts have that plate and an obvious round molded place to put the wire in - it is made to sandwich straight wires.

Good job!

Comment: Turns out the receptacle was bad!

Comment: It's always something, eh?  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this type but have read that the holes in this type make a great connection when the screw is tightened. When you pull on the wire is it in tight?